# Slider in redux-form does not slide smoothly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am using a slider in redux-form. I get the value of the slider in the form, however, the issue is, the slider does not slide smoothly. It slides according to the 'steps' mentioned. How can I fix it?

```
import Slider from "rc-slider";

<Field
  name="Term"                 
  component={(props,input, onChange, onAfterChange) => 
    <Slider 
      value= {props.input.value}
      onChange={props.input.onChange}
      {...props}

      dots
      step={12}
      max={48}

      className="common-slider-style"
      trackStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#00599a" }}
      handleStyle={{
        border: "1px solid #00599a",
        width: "20px",
        height: "20px",
        top: "1px"
      }}
      activeDotStyle={{
        border: "1px solid #00599a",
        width: "10px",
        height: "10px"
      }}

      marks={marks}
      onAfterChange={this.onAfterChange.bind(this)}  
    />
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `step={12}`, the slider will move 12 steps at a time. That is why it is jumping instead of sliding smoothly. If you want it to glide more smoothly, reduce the value in `step`.

According to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider) for the component you use, it must be above 0, and the difference between `max` and `min` must be evenly divisible by `step`.

Comment: it does not work. I have dots ={true}. hence i need steps. steps or no steps, the slider does not slide smoothly.

Comment: The point of `dots` and `steps` is to make the slider jump according to the specified steps, so it is unfortunately not possible to make the slider glide smoothly while setting those props. If you remove both `dots` and `steps` or set them to `false` and `null` respectively, it should slide without jumping.

Comment: thank you for your reply/suggestions. however, none of them worked. finally i got it working. please check the reference: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/51908072-cant-move-the-slider-if-property-value-is-set